# auto-away state under 'structure' deprecated?

Tags: nest-api

I read in Nest's Release Notes "What's New?", in an article titled "New things for fall - October 2016", there is a change to the API structure, the away states will now be either "home" or "away", adding "('auto-away' is deprecated)". It's November 14th, and I'm still seeing the 'auto-away' state being used.   If the 'auto-away' state is deprecated, the 'away' state will mean two things -- away and auto-away. How can an App know if the Away state means that a user manually set the state overriding the Home/Away Assist processing or the state was set by Home/Away Assist processing and will automatically be set to 'home' when appropriate?

By removing the 'auto-away' state, it appears that Nest's API will no longer expose if Home/Away Assist processing is overridden or not -- unless I'm missing a new flag.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true that you can no longer differentiate between an away state that is overridden, i.e. away, and away state that is automatically set, i.e. auto-away.

If you are still seeing auto-away, this is bug and should not be happening.  Could you please provide details as to how to reproduce this?  Are you using real physical devices or using the Nest Home Simulator?  What devices exist on your account and what steps were done to get an auto-away state in the API?

Comment: Why is Nest removing visibility to this information?  Since the automatic processing functionally remains the same, this information must be retained somewhere, just managed differently internally.  As I see it, the API is being upgraded, but removing a feature -- not exactly a good upgrade...

I'm integrated with the API via Firebase, registering a listener for changes to the 'structures' URI.  I'm using real devices, not the simulator.  When the system "determines" that no one is home, the listener is notified of the change, setting the 'away' value to 'auto-away'.

Comment: The fact that the API is still returning "auto-away" is bug and has been reported to Nest engineering.  Thank you for reporting this.